# open url and count how many links contain

Tags: php, codeigniter, dom

I'm looking for a solution using PHP/Dom to get number of links on each page. I use PHPDOM library and this is my own PHP code:

```
public function count_page_links($url = "https://www.rootdomain.com"){
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $link){
        $headers = @get_headers($link->href);
        if(strpos($headers[0], "200")){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: i want to count how many links contain each page of the website

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have now? Also I'd suggest using the built-in DomDocument functions which the first comment links to.

Comment: That looks like `simple_html_dom`, not the builtin `DOM` extension. But in any case... when you have a collection, just `count` it ? `DOMNodeList` has its own `::count()` method. Check your library docs.